# GET requests get sent as "(internal dummy connection)" in Apache 2.4.52

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I'm running a browser game that requests a lot of files from the server while loading. After the user has requested around 200 files, the requests get cancelled in the browser.

The access logs of Apache show `Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)` for the remaining requests.

[image: Network logs of Chrome]

This began happening today, but has worked correctly for many weeks now. Any solutions?

For info, the server is running on Ubuntu 22.04 in an Azure VM.

Comment: Browser? Is this a browser game or a game client? Is this error on the server or the client? We need a lot more info, and it's usually best if you do research and try some things as well, and share that. Do not reply in comments. Use the EDIT button to make your question more complete and clear.